# Flash Air iOS Development: Is it possible to launch a browser from within your applications?

Tags: ios, flash, browser, air

I use Flash Air to develop iOS games. It would be nice to be able to launch a browser from within your applications. Any ideas would be appreciated!!

Comment: Note about the answers below: `StageWebView` opens a web page in a defined rectangle _within_ your app, while `navigateToURL` launches the Safari browser _outside_ your app.  The question seems a bit ambiguous, but both answers are nicely presented below.  :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [StageWebView](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html) to open a web page within your AIR app.

Here's a sample usage to open a page on the right half of the screen (aka stage):

```
private var _web_view:StageWebView;
private function init_stagewebview(url:String):void 
{
  if (_web_view) {
    throw new Error('init_stagewebview() called with existing _web_view - you must call cleanup first');
  }
  _web_view = new StageWebView();
  var stage:Stage = NativeApplication.nativeApplication.activeWindow.stage;
  _web_view.stage = stage;
  _web_view.viewPort = new Rectangle(stage.stageWidth/2,0,stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight);
  _web_view.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, handle_error);
  _web_view.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handle_error);
  _web_view.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, handle_error); 
  _web_view.addEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGING, handle_loc_change);
  _web_view.loadURL(url);
}

private function handle_loc_change(e:LocationChangeEvent=null):void 
{ 
  if (e) {
    var loc:String = e.location;
    trace(" -- webView location changed to: "+loc);

    // Disable the navigation if you want to (this is a common
    // way of passing data from web to AIR):
    // e.preventDefault();
  }
}

private function cleanup_web_view():void 
{
  if (_web_view == null) return;
  _web_view.removeEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, handle_error);
  _web_view.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handle_error);
  _web_view.removeEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, handle_error);
  _web_view.removeEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGING, handle_loc_change);
  _web_view.viewPort = null;
  _web_view.dispose();
  _web_view = null;
}

private function handle_error(e:ErrorEvent):void 
{ 
  if (e) trace("- - - - webView Error:" + e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `navigateToURL()` ([docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL())) from an AIR app launches the system browser app to the URL you specify (leaving your app in the background):

```
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"), "_blank");
```

Comment: But this piece of code would quit my app and open up the browser. I want to keep users within my app...

Comment: instead of "_blank" you can try "_self" or some of the other ones. If that doesn't help, Adrian's answer seems more promising.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the AIR specific class HTMLControl ?
As I understand you want to enable web navigation withing a portion of your screen app.

http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2007/11/09/using-the-htmlcontrol-in-adobe-air-to-parse-html-as-a-data-source/